# Can you delete appengine projects?

Tags: google-app-engine

I just hit my 10 application limit. Is there a way to delete ones where I never finished the idea?

http://appengine.google.com/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

<strike>No, you can't delete apps. You can reuse them, particularly if you intend to use a custom domain anyway, or you can post a request on the official group and one of us Googlers will grant you extra apps. We'd prefer you didn't create a new account.</strike>

App deletion is now supported - just click on 'Application settings' under 'Administration' in your control panel, and click 'delete application'.

Comment: I posted : http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_frm/thread/becc5a3dbacf30fe but alas, no extra apps.

Comment: Give us a chance. I have to sleep too. ;)

Comment: just from a pure point of interest. Why isn't it possible to delete app engine projects. Say I created a dummy one, just for trying out the API etc. But now I do not really need it any more, why shouldn't I be able to just remove it, since it is completely useless??

Comment: Deletion simply isn't implemented yet - it's been lower priority than delivering useful new features to users. You can look forward to it in future, though!

Comment: Deleting apps is supported now http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/adminconsole.html#delete_app

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

Please star this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=335

Comment: not the answer i was looking for... :(. Does creating a new account and transferring ownership work?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to https://appengine.google.com/
2. Click on your project
3. Select Administration - Application Settings
4. At the bottom of the page, you will see "Disable or Delete Application"

Using this you will disable your app. Then it will give you permission to delete app. After 72 hours it will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Hit following URL after you are logged in to Google App Engine :

https://console.developers.google.com/project

Here you will get complete list of applications present in your account along with option to delete these apps.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects

Click on Check box ( Allow only one checkbox at time - For delete )
After check just  Click on delete At top center.